# Adding Medium.com style zoom for images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried using [`zoom`](https://github.com/fat/zoom.js) which is a simple jQuery plugin for image zooming, as seen on Medium.

Here's a [`Demo`](https://fat.github.io/zoom.js).

I followed all the instructions as said by the developer, but I couldn't get it to work.

Here's my [`Fiddle.`](https://jsfiddle.net/8vpc3pk5/1/) It's a simple plugin but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please include your code in your post. Only link to off-site code after it is included in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin you are using requires [`jQuery`](https://jquery.com/). Make sure you have included that in your page. Your JSFiddle does not work as jQuery is NOT included in the fiddle.

To include jQuery into the fiddle select `JAVASCRIPT` in the upper right hand corner of the JavaScript window (bottom left corner) and a menu will pop-up to select various JS libraries to include in your fiddle.

[JSFiddle with jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/8vpc3pk5/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add JQuery in the javascript section. Check my fiddle:

```
<img src="http://fat.github.io/zoom.js/img/palm.jpg" data-action="zoom" width="200px">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/05jqd1eu/